# How come my string function does not return anything?

Tags: c++, string, function, parsing

Either the function does not return anything or it returns an empty string. I am trying to erase everything before next sequence after the `-e` text in the string. For example, `test -e test/file/path` should return `test/file/path` without the space after `-e`. However, when the function does not return anything or it returns an empty string. I cannot find anything wrong with my function please help!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string fileparse(string str) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
        if (str[i] == '-')
            i += 2; //to account for the space after 'e'
    str.erase(str.begin(), str.begin()+i);
    return str;
}

int main()
{

    string str = "test -e test/file/path";
    string vars = fileparse(str);
    cout << vars << endl; //blank
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `i` after your `for` loop has completed?

Comment: after the end of the loop, i is the length of the string. It erases the whole string.

Comment: You have to `break` after you do `i += 2`

Comment: thanks I can't believe I didn't realize that...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (str[i] == '-') {
     i += 3;
     break;
}
```

It stops when being encountered `'-'` symbol. To get rid of `i` is increased by `1`, and to get rid of letter `e` and one space by `2`.

Comment: Yeah this is good. The break leaves the for, but the bracket scoping of the if is what you were really missing as it won't work without, or not in my bad c++ ways.

Answer (score 0):

You have to break out of the for loop because you are letting it finish and 'i' has been incrementing. Then when you reference 'i' it will delete the entire string.